# When is Control.DestroyHandle called?

Tags: .net, winforms

When is this called? More specifically, I have a control I'm creating - how can I release handles when the window is closed. In normal win32 I'd do it during `wm_close` - is `DestroyHandle` the .net equivalent?

---

I don't want to destroy the window handle myself - my control is listening for events on another object and when my control is destroyed, I want to stop listening to those events. Eg:

```
void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    otherObject.Event -= myEventHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally `DestroyHandle` is being called in `Dispose` method. So you need to make sure that all controls are disposed to avoid resource leaks.

Answer (score 2):

`Dispose` does call `DestroyHandle`, but not always. If I close the parent window, then Windows will destroy all child windows. In this situation `Dispose` won't call `DestroyHandle` (since it is already destroyed). In other words, `DestroyHandle` is called to destroy the window, it is not called when the window is destroyed.

The solution is to override either `OnHandleDestroyed`, or `Dispose`. I'm opting for `Dispose`.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want to destroy handle yourself? In my practice I don't remember a case when I was needed to call DestroyHandle explicitly. Could you please explain your case?